# SignalR password authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, .net-5

Hello people of Stackoverflow,

I want to protect access to my hubs by a simple password. On my server-side, where I implement my hubs, I added this code:

AuthRequirement.cs

```
public class AuthRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

AuthHandler.cs

```
    public class AuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AuthRequirement>
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IOptions<AuthorizationCredentials> m_credentials;

    public AuthHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IOptions<AuthorizationCredentials> credentials)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        m_credentials = credentials;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TVosAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if request header contains password 
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null &&
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("password", out var password) &&
                password.Any() && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password.FirstOrDefault()) &&
                password.FirstOrDefault() == "somePassword")
            {
                // Authorization passed  
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            // Return completed task  
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors("ACorsPolicy");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            // Mapping hubs
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ACorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        .....

        // Used for SignalR Authorization
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthHandler>();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("SomeAuthPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthRequirement());
            });
        });

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSignalR();
    }
```

MyHub.cs

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SomeAuthPolicy")]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    // Hub functions
}
```

On my client application, I setup connection as:

```
MyHub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(new Uri($"{url}"),options => options.Headers.Add("password", "somePassword")).Build();
```

The above code works, no exceptions are thrown. On the other hand, if I modify my client to not implement password header or a wrong password as such:

```
MyHub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(new Uri($"{url}")).Build();
```

I get an exception on my server-side:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMEJR4S71B8E", Request id "0HMEJR4S71B8E:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Is there a way to return 404 or something when authorization to SignalR hub fails? Or just make sure my server is not throwing this error?

Comment: As your Exception mentions you have not set a scheme.  If you set up authentication properly (lots of articles) you will get 401 for Not Authorized.